# How to change column header sort image in Datagrid?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid, .net-1.1

In winforms .Net Framework 1.1 , is there any way to change column header sort image in datagrid.

[image]

Comment: In .Net Framework 1.1, there is no DatagridView , we have only Datagrid.

Answer (score -1):

Edit Columns -> Select Required Column -> Edit Property SortMode into NotSortable or Programmatic

Comment: In .Net Framework 1.1 Datagrid , I couldn't find Column Property SortMode